# Does $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=i}^\infty A_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n=i}^\infty A_n$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Are
$$B=\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=i}^\infty A_n \quad C=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n=i}^\infty A_n$$
equivalent sets (i.e. does $B=C$)? I realize that $B$ can be described as all elements that are in an infinite number of sets and $C$ can be described as all elements that are not in a finite number of sets. Can someone provide more characteristics of these sets?

Comment: Your paraphrases give you the answer to your question. Suppose that some point $x$ is in $A_n$ if and only if $n$ is even. Then $x$ is in infinitely many of the sets $A_n$, so $x\in B$, but there are also infinitely sets $A_n$ that do **not** contain $x$; is $x\in C$?

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Examples_2) are some examples.

Comment: Did anyone realize that "all elements that are not in a finite number of sets" has two intepretations which happen to be B and C respectlively?

Comment: @FanZheng: It would certainly be preferable to say ‘that are in all but a finite number of sets’.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I thought about this example. In that case, $x$ is NOT in $C$. But this confused me because, by this definition, $x$ is NOT in a finite number of sets, so shouldn't it exist in $C$?

Comment: @mathjacks: Okay, now I see your problem, I think. Rephrase your description of what’s in $C$: $C$ contains the elements that are in **all but** a finite number of the $A_n$. For each $x\in C$ there are only finitely many $n$ for which $x\notin A_n$. You can see this because by definition there’s an $i$ such that $x\in\bigcap_{n\ge i}A_n$, so any $A_n$ that doesn’t contain $x$ must have $n<i$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks! That clears everything up for me.

Comment: @mathjacks: You’re welcome!

Comment: If they are equal (which they are not in general) their common value is often denoted $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n$ (it's the limit of the sets, seen as characteristic functions in the product $\{0,1\}^X$ in the product topology, which can serve as a justification.)